# Add filtering logic for the badges page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How about adding a filter to [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page? Most of the stack overflow users will take a sneak at this page many times when his/her reputation starts growing. Its just a place for virtual satisfaction. This is similar to achieving points in video games, only in stack overflow, the badges and reputation means "knowledge". If you get addicted to it, the side effect you're gonna acquire is knowledge.

Enough for the build up. Why not add a filter to the badges page to show "only" bronze, silver, gold badge OR have a sort by badge feature. This can be done without occupying any extra space in the site at all. There is already this legend on the right side describing about badges. When user clicks now, nothing happens, instead append the filtering logic of the badges there?

Its a pure suggestion, nothing else.

Comment: I think this is a great idea, and you're right it wouldn't take any extra space since the categories are currently listed on the right (and clickable! although clicking them does nothing).

Answer (score 2):

Right now i don't feel like this is necessary.  There aren't that many badges.  It is still easy enough to mentally filter them out if you want.

Comment: Can you add a status-completed tag to this question of mine since it was asked like a couple of years before and I saw recently it has been indeed implemented